# SQL - Remove decimal and include its value in the number

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal

I don't think the title of this topic illustrates well what I need to do, I have a table with numbers like this:

```
Number - 32.4
```

What I want to do is to remove the decimal value of the number and include the value that is on the right of the decimal point to the left, it has to be like this:

```
Number - 324
```

I tried this query:

```
UPDATE table
SET Number = CAST(Number AS INT)
WHERE Number LIKE '%.%'
```

It removed the . but also remove the value that is on the right of the decimal point. Like this:

```
Number - 32
```

Any clues for this question??

Comment: What is the data type of the column?  Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It is float, I'll tag the database, it is SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

If all the numbers have two decimal points, then you can use:

```
UPDATE table
    SET Number = CAST(Number * 100 AS INT);
```

But perhaps your intent is to convert to a string and then back to an int:

```
UPDATE table
    SET Number = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(Number as VARCHAR(255)), '.', '') AS INT);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! The second example worked perfectly for me!